# How to make a wheel menu like in JB camera

Tags: android

I have a button in my app and when someone presses it and keeps the finger down a pop out wheel menu should appear (like the one the JB camera has).

It will look like this

[image]

In the center there will be a button, when your finger is down the wheel appears, when you lift it it disappears

I will make the wheel appear with this piece of code

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {


                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                        wheel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Log.w("app", "Action up");
                        return true;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                        wheel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.w("app", "Action down");
                  }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Now i have a problem, how can i position the buttons of the wheel? (i don't want to use the whole wheel image, i would prefer exporting only one piece since they all look alike)

Also after the wheel appears i'd like to select one of the options by lifting my finger above one of them with ACTION_UP how can i achieve this?